# Group by in JavaScript - flat array to nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, group-by, javascript-objects

I have this list in my front-end typescript file:

**poMonths:**

```
0: {id: 1, companyName: "company14", companyId: 14, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-12-15T00:00:00", purchaseMonthString: "Dec-2019" , year: 2019, month: "December"}
1: {id: 2, companyName: "company5", companyId: 5, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-12-15T00:00:00", …}
2: {id: 3, companyName: "company13", companyId: 13, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-11-15T00:00:00", …}
3: {id: 4, companyName: "company14", companyId: 14, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-11-15T00:00:00", …}
4: {id: 5, companyName: "company5", companyId: 5, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-10-15T00:00:00", …}
5: {id: 6, companyName: "company14", companyId: 14, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2020-09-15T00:00:00", …}
6: {id: 7, companyName: "company7", companyId: 7, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2020-09-15T00:00:00", …}
```

I would like to get a nested tree json out of it grouped by compnayName and year properties, something similar to this but in JSON format:

[image]

I have found this bit of code however it doesn't return the results completely, it needs to be tweaked a bit:

```
keys = [
    'year',
    'companyName'
  ];

groupBy() {
    const drill = (o, key, ...keys) =>
      key ? drill((o[key] = o[key] || {}), ...keys) : o;
    const result = {};
    for (const e of this.poMonths) {
      const key = drill(
        result,
        e.companyName,
        e.year,

        e.month
      );
    }
    return result;
  }
```

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your tree using [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It starts with an empty object and will assign default value whenver there's no object/array defined under specific key yet (right handside of `||` operator will get executed):

```js
let input = [{id: 1, companyName: "company14", companyId: 14, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-12-15T00:00:00", year: 2019, month: "December"},
{id: 2, companyName: "company5", companyId: 5, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-12-15T00:00:00", year: 2019, month: "December"},
{id: 3, companyName: "company13", companyId: 13, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-11-15T00:00:00", year: 2019, month: "November"},
{id: 4, companyName: "company14", companyId: 14, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-11-15T00:00:00", year: 2019, month: "December"},
{id: 5, companyName: "company5", companyId: 5, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2019-10-15T00:00:00", year: 2019, month: "October"},
{id: 6, companyName: "company14", companyId: 14, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2020-09-15T00:00:00", year: 2020, month: "September"},
{id: 7, companyName: "company7", companyId: 7, flActive: true, purchaseMonth: "2020-09-15T00:00:00", year: 2020, month: "September"}]

let months = { "09": "September", "10": "October", "11": "November", "12": "December" }

let result = input.reduce((state,current) => {
   let {companyName, year, month} = current;
   
   let company = state[companyName] || (state[companyName] = {});
   let yearObj = company[year] || (company[year] = {});
   let monthArr = yearObj[month] || (yearObj[month] = []);
   monthArr.push(current);
   
   return state;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @EfronA. modified my answer

Comment: do you know how I can have the "id" attribute at the "month" level? At the moment, id would be shown as a child underneath the month, however, each month would only have one id underneath it, so I would like to have the id at the month level. How would you do this?

Comment: @EfronA. please open another question in order to keep this one clear

Comment: Thanks, slightly different question based on your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744446/types-group-by-in-javascript-typescript-nested-json-to-a-typed-nested-array

Comment: Great answer - quick question. What would be the easiest way to remove the brackets from the months payload => "December": [{ to "December": {. Also, is it possible to remove the duplicate keys in the nested portion (companyName, year, month)?