# How to group array with multiple objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array

```
{
"id": 5308,
"empId": 202,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 50000
},
{
"id": 5309,
"empId": 173,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 30000
},
{
"id": 5310,
"empId": 212,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 21100
},
{
"id": 5311,
"empId": 163,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 43000
},
{
"id": 5312,
"empId": 116,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 52000
},
{
"id": 5313,
"empId": 223,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 21100
},
{
"id": 5314,
"empId": 231,
"loc": 1,
"salMonth": "1",
"salYear": "2020",
"salDate": "2020-01",
"netSal": 42217
}
```

I have to group this array by two colums, that is empId, salDate.

And the expected result should like:

```
{
  "202": {
    "2020-01": {
      "salId": xx,
      "salary": xxx
    },
    "2020-02": {
      "salId": xxx,
      "salary": xxxx
    },
    "2020-03": {
      "salId": xxx,
      "salary": xxxx
    }
  },
  "203": {
    "2020-01": {
      "salId": xx,
      "salary": xxx
    },
    "2020-02": {
      "salId": xxx,
      "salary": xxxx
    },
    "2020-03": {
      "salId": xxx,
      "salary": xxxx
    }
  },

}
```

Thanks Advance ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I got solution by following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367205/group-by-in-javascript-flat-array-to-nested-json). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop could solve your problem.
try this.

```js
let modifiedData = {}
let data = [{
    "id": 5308,
    "empId": 202,
    "loc": 1,
    "salMonth": "1",
    "salYear": "2020",
    "salDate": "2020-01",
    "netSal": 50000
  },
  {
    "id": 5309,
    "empId": 173,
    "loc": 1,
    "salMonth": "1",
    "salYear": "2020",
    "salDate": "2020-01",
    "netSal": 30000
  },
  {
    "id": 5310,
    "empId": 212,
    "loc": 1,
    "salMonth": "1",
    "salYear": "2020",
    "salDate": "2020-01",
    "netSal": 21100
  }
];

//loop your data and create modifed data
data.map(d => {
  if(!modifiedData[d.empId]) { // check weather empId already exists or not
     modifiedData[d.empId] = []
  }
  modifiedData[d.empId].push({[d.salDate]:{salId: d.id, salary: d.netSal}})
})
console.log(modifiedData) // print final data
```